# jquery - how to access object values set in another function?

Tags: jquery, object, widget

I'm lost again.

I'm using the jquery widget factory. I declare a global object that keeps track of visited pages. I set this in one function and need to access it from another function, which I can't get to work.

Can someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong here:

```
(function($,window){
$.widget("mobile.multiview",$.mobile.widget, {
       vars: { 
          hist:{},
          // there is 4 panel elements, which contain several pages each
          $panel:$("div:jqmData(role='panel')") 
          },
    _create: function() {
           // access vars
           var self = this;

           // run through all panels, retrieve each panel ID
           $panels.each(function(index) {
           var id = $(this).jqmData('id');

           // sorry, this was pasted to quickly
           // for each panel I'm setting an object 
           // and adding the ID of the first page (data-show="first") to the object
           self.vars.hist[id] = ['#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(role="page")').attr('id')];
           console.log("entry made");
           //console.log("entry: "+self.vars.hist[id][0]);
            });
          },
     crumble: function(event, data, page) {
          var self = $( '#'+page.attr('id') ),
              $crumPanel = $( '#'+page.attr('id') ).closest('div:jqmData(role="panel")'),
              $backup = self.vars.hist[$crumPanel.jqmData('id')][self.vars.hist[$crumPanel.jqmData('id')].length-1];
              // this stays undefined...
              console.log( $backup );
```

I hoped by declaring `hist` on a global level it would be possible to access the stored information, similar to other variables I create within the vars section. But it isn't... I guess only the empty object is stored globally.

So how can I access the "local" data, filled into the object inside _create?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timing issue. I set crumble to fire on `pagecreate`, which fired earlier than _create. So I could not access the object elements from crumble as they were not set.

By binding to `pageinit` inside _create (this supercedes `pagecreate` event, I can call the hist object from other functions as well.

I put it in the global vars to basically do just that. Define it on a widget-wide basis and make it accessible from all widget functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have never used that widget plugin, but you could consider using [jQuery's .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of global vars.
You would probably do something like this:

```
$(ElementID).data('name', '#'+$(this).attr('id'));
```

and to access it in another function:

```
var mydata = $(ElementID).data('name');
```

Comment: Hm. I'm setting a lot of data() already. Let's see if this also fits :)

Answer (score 0):

In "crumble", you're defining self to be what I assume is the widget's element on the page?

In the context of a widget method, this === the instance of the plugin.  this.element === the jquerified element that the widget was created on top of.

What you're trying to do won't work because the jquerified element doesn't have the "vars" var, the widget's prototype does.  Try doing console.log( this.vars.hist ) in the method to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I consoled both _create and crumble function. Both times console.log(this.vars.hist) returns OBJECT. So... what does this mean? I'm a newbie to Objects...at least there is one...

Comment: Got it to work. It was a matter of timing... I fired crumble on "pagecreate" event and this was running before _create was fired, so I was trying to look up elements in the history before setting them. By binding to "pageinit" event inside _create I can assign elements to the object and call them from crumble. Only ... the page takes forever to load now. But it works.